# how convert result of ObjectGraphMeasurer.measure(object) to bytes?

Tags: java, memory

I want to calculate size of object in memory in java, so I used `Caliper` library and used the following method `ObjectGraphMeasurer.measure` that result the following:

```
Footprint{Objects=270813, NonNullRefs=353968, NullRefs=1016731, Primitives=[int x 388091, double x 4375548, long x 2609976, boolean x 6398, float x 76765, char x 66658]}
```

Firstly I don't know what mean by `NonNullRefs` and `NullRefs`,
secondly I want to convert this result to bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I think nonNullRefs means that the thing it is Referencing is not null and nullRefs mean that the thing is null.
Don't know the answer to the last question.

Hope that helps.